# what does git log --graph --all --pretty= do?

Tags: git, terminal

I was targeting to print `git log --graph` without any commit detail. Thus making it as compact as possible.

So I created a test repository and tested various output.
I tried pretty and found out that `--pretty=` argument didn't print any commit detail (which is what I wanted). But It also made it difficult to interpret.

```
$ git log --graph --all --pretty=oneline

* 7387eb7a4c5e29f027b0f1cd3077b7ddb5ecf7fd 2nd commit in secBranch
* a5fc3b06605baf0e0d9bcf07da3b8cc849dabf35 first commit in secBranch
| * 7df665d9ed006e3271a506a4f688af4d69ef1f28 first master commit after branching
|/  
* 44b64f360018e241bfabb65ec172c653fff9ca95 this commmit will be branched
* 50123a9e38e65e2ab97d07d3ad0621b099091ffa initial commit
* 1b133613e6194250f8a0a96f68fa907463d57e8d initial commit
```

and with `--pretty=` option it turned into

```
$ git log --graph --all --pretty=

* * | * 
|/  * * *
```

can someone please explain the similarity I'm missing in those two output?

[The link for my test repository](https://github.com/BorhnN/GitGraphTest)

Comment: `--pretty=<format string>` is to format the output. At least, use `--pretty=%h` to show which commit each * represents. %h is the placeholder of the abbreviation form of a hash value. If `format string` is empty, of course the output is weired. But in my machine, with `--pretty=` it works like without `--pretty`.

Comment: `--pretty` is a formatting directive, obviously leaving `={empty string}` isn't a case the developpers anticipated, and `git` interprets this as "print an empty description string for each commit".  Drop the `=` (doc says this would be equal to `=medium`) ; read `git help log` for more help.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it now. This output was essentially a normal graph without any commit details. It was looking weird because it was missing the nextline character along with other details.

This command fixed it.

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --all --pretty=%n

*
|
*
|
| *
|/
|
*
|
*
|
*
```